# SSRS Border around a group fails at end of page

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-grouping

I would like to put a border around each entire group. I have found an expression online to help with this, but it  has one flaw. When the group extends to a new page, the bottom border of the last item, and the top border for the first item on the next page do not appear.

Code for top border

```
=Iif(Fields!ROWNUM.Value = First(Fields!ROWNUM.Value, "EVENT"),"Solid",nothing)
```

Code for bottom border.

```
=Iif(Fields!ROWNUM.Value = Last(Fields!ROWNUM.Value, "EVENT"),"Solid",nothing)
```

based on the logic of this expression, I can completely understand why it does this, but I want to know if there is any way to solve this. Unfortunately inserting a page break between instances of the group is not an option, some of these groups are large and would leave pages almost entirely blank. I believe that you cannot use the global variable page number outside of the header/footer. Is there a "Page break" variable that i can use to say before or after page break?.

Any ideas would be great! thanks